# Why Acumatica can't find method

Tags: acumatica

I'm working with Acumatica 5.30.2347. I have following selector in my graph:

```
var check = PXSelect<POLine,Where<POLine.orderType, Equal<POOrderType.regularOrder>>>
                       .Select(this);
```

but when I try to execute it, I receive following error:
Method not found: 'Void PX.Data.PXLineAttribute..ctor'(System.Type).

Initially I've got an impression, that this error message appeared because class PXLineAttribute doesn't have constructor which accepts System.Type, but with help of reflector I've discovered that PXLineAttribute has following declaration:

```
public PXLineNbrAttribute(System.Type sourceType)
  : this(sourceType, false)
{
}
```

which gives me idea that PXLineNbrAttribute has needed constructor. So I have two questions: Why Acumatica Framework can't find constructor of PXLineNbrAttribute? How to help Acumatica to find before mentioned constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your VS class library project references to Acumatica assemblies. I would suspect them to reference assemblies from a different Acumatica build and therefore cause "Method not found ..." errors at runtime.

Comment: I've double checked and still I'm sure that my class library references correct dll version